# It is posible to embed the Unreal Engine 4/Unity3D into an iOS native app?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, unreal-engine4

I have to develop an iOS native app that renders a 3D model on the background with some iOS native UI over the render, and obviously it has to be a 2 ways communication between the 3D engine and the UI, for example to call an animation from the UI and know when the animation have finished.

I found [this post](http://www.the-nerd.be/2014/08/06/add-unity3d-in-a-native-ios-application/) that shows how to embed a Unity3D scene but it does not explain anything about the communication.

I would like to know if this is posible with Unity3D and UE4, if so, how, and what would be the best/easiest?

Thanks =)

Comment: That doesn't sound viable to me.  You are looking at creating the app in UE4 or Unity and then finding a way to present a native view controller from within those game engines.  I believe that is possible, at least with Unity.

Comment: I'm not really sure what do you mean... Are you suggesting me to instantiate the iOS views inside the Unity/UE4 scene? The thing is that we have an actual app that uses our own 3D engine with all the views over it. And we want to keep the logic of the app and change the 3D engine to something more stable, efficient and scalable.

Comment: Yeah; if you intend to use UE4 or Unity then I'm suggesting then that is the one-and-only app.  You *should* then be able to overlay views over the engine views.

Answer (score 1):

After messing around a few days with Unity, I found this tutorial: http://www.markuszancolo.at/2015/09/integrating-unity-into-a-native-ios-app-example/ right now I think this solution is valid enough for what I want to do. 
Basically I have to create a project for Unity, and create a build for Debug. This will create an iOS project for xcode and then I have to take control of the AppDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

In UE4 you will likely need to get the engine's source in order to put in the necessary dependencies for the communication from GUI to the engine. Personally, I think it would work best if you implement custom GUI with the engine into the app, that would likely save you time and trouble. However, if native UI is necessary, then digging into UE4's source would likely be your best bet.

Please contact me if you need further assistance!